# Making a method trigger another method in a Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, events, event-handling

Consider the following code.

```
import edu.cmu.ri.createlab.terk.robot.finch.Finch;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RobotControl extends JFrame { 
    public static void main (String args[])  {

    RobotControl GUI = new RobotControl(); //GUI is the name of my object.
    GUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GUI.setSize(300,300);
    GUI.setVisible(true);
    GUI.setTitle("RobotControl");
}


    private JButton foward;



    public RobotControl() { //constructor
    setLayout (new FlowLayout());

    foward = new JButton("foward");
    add(foward);

    ActionListener e = new event();
    foward.addActionListener(e);
    }
             public class event implements ActionListener {
                       public void actionPerformed1(ActionEvent e){


    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

}

Now consider the following code that would make my finch robot move foward for 10 seconds.

```
            Finch myf = new Finch();
            myf.setWheelVelocities(255, 255, 10000);
```

Now, my question is, would it be possible to execute the second piece of code as a result of clicking the foward button created on the GUI, from the first piece of code? If so how would i go about it. I have tried putting the finch code into the actionListener class but nothing happens. where am i going wrong. I need advice.

Comment: 1- Not with the `myf.sleep(5000);` and `System.exit(0);` in the `ActionListener`. 2- What is `Finch`?

Comment: Finch is a small robot i am using to learn java. just google finch robot.

Comment: It seems that you're confused about `ActionListener`s. Have you looked at [Oracle's tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, yes.

First, you need to maintain an instance of `Finch` as a instance variable...

```
public class RobotControl extends JFrame { 
    private Finch finch;
    //...
}
```

You need to create an instance of `Finch`...

```
public RobotControl {
    finch = new Finch();
}
```

Then in your `ActionListener`, you need to "communicate" with `Finch`

```
public void actionPerformed1(ActionEvent e){
    myf.setWheelVelocities(255, 255, 10000);
}
```

The long answer, it's likely that you are going to have to issue multiple commands in sequence, the problem with this, is this process is likely to block the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing from responding to new incoming events and making it look like your application has "stopped"

While there are multiple ways you might alleviate this problem, if you don't need `Finch` to communicate with the UI (such as report status of motors or something), you could simply use a single threaded `Executor` of some kind and simply issue a sequence of commands via it.

If you need to provide feedback to the client UI, things become considerably more complicated...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code:

```
-------------------------
RobotControl.java
myrobot = new Finch();

foward = new JButton("foward");
    add(foward);
    forward.addActionListener(new ForwardButtonListener(myrobot));


-------------------------
ForwardButtonListener.java
public class ForwardButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    Finch robotToControl;

    public FowardButtonListener(Finch aRobot) {
        robotToControl = aRobot;
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        robotToControl.setWheelVelocities(255, 255, 10000);
    }

}
-------------------------
```

Comment: It took me about 10 minutes to figure out your sample code due to the few changes you made but it works perfectly. You've been such a great help. Many thanks.